# Unable to call lifecycle methods in Strapi models?

Tags: strapi

I have a Strapi project with a MongoDB database and a simple `Post` model. This model has, among others, a `slug` field with the following attributes:

```
type: string,
unique: true,
required: true
```

For testing purposes, I am attempting to modify this field's value before committing it to the DB, via one of Strapi's lifecycle methods:

```
module.exports = {
  // Before saving a value.
  // Fired before an `insert` or `update` query.
  beforeSave: async (model) => {
   // Set the password.
   const newslug = model.slug + '-test';
   model.slug = newslug;
  },
};
```

But the method just doesn't seem to get fired as expected when I `save` a post on my admin page. The post, along with its `slug`, gets upserted to the DB without the modification shown in the code above. Am I misunderstanding the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NoSQL database (Mongo)

```
beforeSave: async (model) => {
  if (model.content) {
    model.wordCount = model.content.length;
  }
},
beforeUpdate: async (model) => {
  if (model.getUpdate().content) {
    model.update({
      wordCount:  model.getUpdate().content.length
    });
  }
},
```

If you are using SQL (SQLite, Postgres, MySQL)

```
beforeSave: async (model, attrs, options) => {
  if (attrs.content) {
    attrs.wordCount = attrs.content.length;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    async afterUpdate(event){
      const rawBuilder = await strapi.db.connection.raw(
      "SELECT * FROM nameTable;"
      );

        console.log(rawBuilder, "RESULT:::");

    }
```

Example to execute a SQL query afer update some value in database or strapi, using knex strapi connection